# Рекурсивный вызов суперкласса. Рефлексия

Tags: java, рекурсия, наследование, рефлексия

Нужно написать рекурсивный метод, показывающий всех родителей переданного в параметр объекта, кроме Object. Например, для объекта кошка: Кошачие, Млекопитающие, Животные...

Пробовал так, но получил бесконечную рекурсию:

```
public class ShowParent {

ArrayList list = new ArrayList();


public void getAllParentsExceptObject(Class investigatedClass) {
    Class currentClass = investigatedClass.getClass();
    list.add(currentClass.getSuperclass());
    getAllParentsExceptObject((Class) list.get(list.size()-1));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TheCat cat = new TheCat();
    ShowParent sp = new ShowParent();
    sp.getAllParentsExceptObject(cat.getClass());
    System.out.println(sp.list.toString());
}
```

}

И так:

```
public void getAllParentsExceptObject() {
    if (!this.getClass().equals(Object.class)) {
    this.getClass().getSuperclass();
    getAllParentsExceptObject();
}}
```

Та же бесконечная рекурсия

Comment: Каковы ваши попытки решения задачи? SO не решает задачи за вас, а лишь помогает и направляет.

Comment: Предчувствуя, что ваш вопрос могут закрыть и рассчитывая на вашу самостоятельность, заранее подскажу направление в решении задачи: рекурсивно вызывайте у теекущего класса (`getClass()`) метод `getSuperclass()` до тех пор, пока не упретесь в `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А нельзя совсем просто?

```
public List<Class> getAllParentsExceptObject(List<Class> parents, Class investigatedClass) {
    Class currentClass = investigatedClass;
    if(currentClass.equals(Object.class))
        return parents;
    parents.add(currentClass);
    Class superClass=currentClass.getSuperclass());
    return getAllParentsExceptObject(parents, superClass);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TheCat cat = new TheCat();
    ShowParent sp = new ShowParent();
    List<Class> parents=sp.getAllParentsExceptObject(new ArrayList<Class>(), cat.getClass());
    System.out.println(parents);
}
```

Comment: вариант рабочий, но нужен именно рекурсивный поиск

Comment: `getAllParentsExceptObject()` разве не рекурсивный?

Comment: разобрался, попробовал запустить, тоже бесконечная рекурсия. Почему - не понимаю

Comment: Проблема может быть только в этой строке: `currentClass.equals(Object.class)` - в условии выхода из рекурсии. Под рукой нет компилятора, так что дальше уж сами. Надо переформулировать условие выхода из рекурсии.

Comment: я прогнал в Debug, такое ощущение, что он один и тот же класс гоняет, вместо того, что б подниматься по родителям

Comment: ЗАРАБОТАЛО. Проблема была в том, что мы уже передаем в метод класс. Не нужно вызывать getClass() в строке Class currentClass = investigatedClass.getClass();

Comment: исправил в ответе.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с использованием `Stream API`:

```
public static Stream<Class<?>> getSuperclasses(Class<?> clazz) {
    if (Object.class.equals(clazz)) {
        return Stream.empty();
    } else {
        return Stream.concat(
                Stream.of(clazz),
                getSuperclasses(clazz.getSuperclass()));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(
            getSuperclasses(TheCat.class)
                    .map(Class::getSimpleName)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
}
```

Comment: Просто интересуюсь - как это будет с точки зрения эффективности? или памяти?  Рекурсивная конкатенация стримов.

Comment: @tym32167, я полностью согласен, что данный вариант будет проигрывать, как по скорости, так и по памяти варианту с изначальной инициализацией `List`-а и использованием его на всех шагах рекурсии. На счет варианта, когда `List` будет создаваться на каждом шаге рекурсии - нужно проводить бенчмарки, но возможно вариант с конкатенацией будет быстрее. Указанный вариант приведен исключительно для ознакомления с доступными вариантами решения и не претендует на звание самого эффективного.